# Identificar sequência de caracteres entre dois trechos conhecidos em uma string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

Gostaria que me ajudassem no seguinte:

Dado isto

```
CGC UUC GCU UUG GAA AAU UUG UGU GUU UUU UGU GGC UGC UCG CUG CUC AAA UUG UUC GCU GCU UUU UGU GUC CUG GCU GCU UUU AUU AUU UUA CGC UGC UUG GCG CUG CUY UUA CGC UGC UUG GGC UUG UUG UGG CUU UGG UUG UUU GUU UAU UAY GCU GCU CUU GUU GUU GUU GCU UGU UGU GCC UAU GGC
```

Eu tenho que fazer um programa que leia esta sequência e que, ao encontrar um `UAG`, guarde todas a letras até encontrar um `UAA`.

Por exemplo, `UAG UGG GAU UUA UAA`.

Como é que eu faço isto?

Comment: Seja bem-vindo ao site. Convido-te a fazer o [tour] para aprender o básico do funcionamento do site e já ler o guia de [ask]. Você poderia melhorar sua pergunta detalhando melhor qual foi a dificuldade encontrada? Você já tentou fazer algo? Deu algum erro? Qual? Por favor, utilize o botão de [edit] para adicionar essas informações.

Comment: Nesta string de exemplo não contém nenhuma ocorrência de `UAG'.

Comment: O seu dado de exemplo não possui a sequencia `UAG UGG GAU UUA UAA`, certo ?

Comment: E caso encontre várias sequências? Ou paras quando finalizares a primeira?

Comment: Não, o meu exemplo não possui a sequência.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode construir uma [máquina de estados finita](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A1quina_de_estados_finita) com apenas 2 estados para resolver o seu problema:

```
def pesquisar( seq, inicio, fim ):
    estado = 0
    ret = []
    aux = []

    for x in seq:
        if estado == 0:
            if x == inicio:
                aux = [ x ]
                estado = 1
        elif estado == 1:
            aux.append( x );
            if x == fim:
                ret.append(aux)
                estado = 0

    return ret


sequencia = ['CGC','UUC','GCU','UUG','GAA','AAU','UUG','UGU','GUU','UUU','UGU','GGC','UGC','UCG','CUG','CUC','AAA','UUG','UUC','GCU','GCU','UUU','UGU','GUC','CUG','GCU','GCU','UUU','AUU','AUU','UUA','CGC','UGC','UUG','GCG','CUG','CUY','UUA','CGC','UGC','UUG','GGC','UUG','UUG','UGG','CUU','UGG','UUG','UUU','GUU','UAU','UAY','GCU','GCU','CUU','GUU','GUU','GUU','GCU','UGU','UGU','GCC','UAU','GGC']

print(pesquisar( sequencia, inicio = 'UGU', fim = 'UGC' ))
```

Saída:

```
[['UGU', 'GUU', 'UUU', 'UGU', 'GGC', 'UGC'],
 ['UGU', 'GUC', 'CUG', 'GCU', 'GCU', 'UUU', 'AUU', 'AUU', 'UUA', 'CGC', 'UGC']]
```

**EDIT:**

Máquinas de estado podem ser construídas em `Python` com o uso de `yield`, segue uma maneira alternativa de solucionar o problema com um código ainda mais compacto:

```
def pesquisar( seq, inicio, fim ):
    ret = []
    for i in seq:
        if i == inicio or ret:
             ret.append(i)
        if i == fim and ret:
            yield ret
            ret = []

sequencia = ['CGC','UUC','GCU','UUG','GAA','AAU','UUG','UGU','GUU','UUU','UGU','GGC','UGC','UCG','CUG','CUC','AAA','UUG','UUC','GCU','GCU','UUU','UGU','GUC','CUG','GCU','GCU','UUU','AUU','AUU','UUA','CGC','UGC','UUG','GCG','CUG','CUY','UUA','CGC','UGC','UUG','GGC','UUG','UUG','UGG','CUU','UGG','UUG','UUU','GUU','UAU','UAY','GCU','GCU','CUU','GUU','GUU','GUU','GCU','UGU','UGU','GCC','UAU','GGC']

print(list(pesquisar( sequencia, inicio = 'UGU', fim = 'UGC')))
```

Saída:

```
[['UGU', 'GUU', 'UUU', 'UGU', 'GGC', 'UGC'],
 ['UGU', 'GUC', 'CUG', 'GCU', 'GCU', 'UUU', 'AUU', 'AUU', 'UUA', 'CGC', 'UGC']]
```

Comment: Hummm... Alguma coisa `pythonica` me diz que isso pode ser simplificado muito mais por meio de uma `List Comprehension`...

Answer (score 2):

Acho que isso pode te ajudar.

```
comeco = "CGC"
fim = "AAA"
string = "CGC UUC GCU UUG GAA AAU UUG UGU GUU UUU UGU GGC UGC UCG CUG CUC AAA UUG UUC GCU GCU UUU UGU GUC CUG GCU GCU UUU AUU AUU UUA CGC UGC UUG GCG CUG CUY UUA CGC UGC UUG GGC UUG UUG UGG CUU UGG UUG UUU GUU UAU UAY GCU GCU CUU GUU GUU GUU GCU UGU UGU GCC UAU GGC"
seqs = string.split(" ")
resp = ""
for i in range(0, len(seqs)):
    if seqs[i] == comeco:
        resp += seqs[i]
        while seqs[i] != fim:
            i += 1
            if i == len(seqs):
                break
            else:
                resp += " "+seqs[i]
        break

print(resp)
```